# Document Date Not specific ax 2012 x++ purchase orders

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm trying to create a PO in ax 2012. Now it will create the PO but i'm also trying to post it but i get the error: Document date has not been specified and the PO has been cancelled.  I'm setting the document date as you can see in the purch parameters but it doesn't like it.. and throws the error. I replaced some of the IDs in this example with junk data FYI.

```
NumberSeq numberSeq;
Purchtable Purchtable;
PurchLine PurchLine;
PurchParmTable purchParmTable;
PurchFormLetter purchFormLetter;
InventDimId _inventDimId;
DocumentDate docDate;
PurchParmUpdate purchParmUpdate;
PurchFormletterParmData     purchFormLetterParmData;
Date myDate;
    str test;



changeCompany("SOMECOMPANY") //Inserts into specified company
{
   //numRefPurchaseOrderId()
ttsbegin;
numberSeq = NumberSeq::newGetNum(purchParameters::numRefPurchId());
_inventDimId="INVENTDIMID";


// Initialize Purchase order values
Purchtable.initValue();
Purchtable.PurchId = numberSeq.num();


Purchtable.OrderAccount = 'SOMEACCOUNT';
Purchtable.initFromVendTable();
if (!Purchtable.validateWrite())
{
throw Exception::Error;
}
Purchtable.insert();


// Initialize Purchase Line items
PurchLine.PurchId = Purchtable.PurchId;
PurchLine.ItemId = 'SOMEITEMID';
PurchLine.InventDimId=_inventDimId;
PurchLine.createLine(true, true, true, true, true, false);


ttscommit;

//PO confirmation


    ttsBegin;
    test="11/26/2018";
    myDate=str2Date(test,213); //month/day/year
   // myDate=mkDate(11, 25, 2018);

      // Create PurchParamUpdate table
    purchFormLetterParmData = PurchFormletterParmData::newData(
        DocumentStatus::PurchaseOrder,
        VersioningUpdateType::Initial);

    purchFormLetterParmData.parmOnlyCreateParmUpdate(true);
    purchFormLetterParmData.createData(false);
    purchParmUpdate = purchFormLetterParmData.parmParmUpdate();

    // Set PurchParmTable table

    purchParmTable.clear();
    purchParmTable.TransDate                = SystemDateGet();
    purchParmTable.DocumentDate = myDate;
    purchParmTable.Ordering                 = DocumentStatus::PurchaseOrder;
    purchParmTable.ParmJobStatus            = ParmJobStatus::Waiting;
    purchParmTable.PurchId                  = purchTable.PurchId;
    purchParmTable.PurchName                = purchTable.PurchName;
    purchParmTable.DeliveryName             = purchTable.DeliveryName;
    purchParmTable.DeliveryPostalAddress    = purchTable.DeliveryPostalAddress;
    purchParmTable.OrderAccount             = purchTable.OrderAccount;
    purchParmTable.CurrencyCode             = purchTable.CurrencyCode;
    purchParmTable.InvoiceAccount           = purchTable.InvoiceAccount;
    purchParmTable.ParmId                   = purchParmUpdate.ParmId;
    purchParmTable.insert();


    purchFormLetter = PurchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PurchaseOrder);
    purchFormLetter.transDate(systemDateGet());
    purchFormLetter.proforma(false);
    purchFormLetter.specQty(PurchUpdate::All);
    purchFormLetter.purchTable(purchTable);

// purchFormLetter = purchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PurchaseOrder);   
//purchFormLetter.update(purchtable, // Purchase record Buffer
//strFmt("Inv_%1", purchTable.PurchId), // Invoice Number
//systemdateget()); // Transaction date


    purchFormLetter.parmParmTableNum(purchParmTable.ParmId);
    purchFormLetter.parmId(purchParmTable.ParmId);
    purchFormLetter.purchParmUpdate(purchFormLetterParmData.parmParmUpdate());
    purchFormLetter.run();

        ttsCommit;




purchFormLetter = purchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::Invoice);
purchFormLetter.update(purchtable, // Purchase record Buffer
strFmt("Inv_%1", purchTable.PurchId), // Invoice Number
systemdateget()); // Transaction date



if (PurchTable::find(purchTable.PurchId).DocumentStatus == DocumentStatus::Invoice)
{
    info(strfmt("Posted invoiced journal for purchase order %1",purchTable.PurchId));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error you need either specify the document date or change the following parameter to `None` or `Warning`

[image]

Comment: but i need the document date and i'm supplying it.. the issue is for some reason its saying its not there but it is